# How to use Where with IEnumerable assignment?

Tags: c#, linq

I am assigning this:

```
IEnumerable<ProductUser> products = myP2Locator.GetMasterDBC().ProductUsers;
```

However I need where UserId = userId

userId is my function argument...

Can someone please tell me how I filter this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mean:

```
IEnumerable<ProductUser> products = myP2Locator
                                    .GetMasterDBC()
                                    .ProductUsers
                                    .Where(pu => pu.UserId == userId);
```

Comment: Thanks I needed this version.

Answer (score 1):

Justin's answer is completely correct. It's worth noting that:

```
IEnumerable<ProductUser> products = from pu in myP2Locator.GetMasterDBC().ProductUsers
                                          where pu.UserId == userId
                                          select pu;
```

Will get turned into pretty much the same thing as in his answer. You will see both syntaxes being used, so it's good to be familiar with both.